# CakePHP 3: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 10 disk I/O error

Tags: cakephp, iis, sqlite, microsoft-distributed-file-system, nlb

I'm serving CakePHP 3.x based sites off a Network Load Balanced (NLB) IIS 10 cluster. The php files reside on an external DFS share. When run with debug enabled, CakePHP throws the following error:

```
2017-08-16 13:45:39 Error: Fixture creation for "requests" failed "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 10 disk I/O error"
2017-08-16 13:45:39 Warning: Warning (512): Fixture creation for "requests" failed "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 10 disk I/O error" in [\\MY.DOMAIN.COM\WEBAPPS\Sites\some_site\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\TestSuite\Fixture\TestFixture.php, line 306]
Request URL: /
Client IP: 10.1.2.250
Trace:
Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler::handleError() - CORE\src\Error\BaseErrorHandler.php, line 146
Cake\TestSuite\Fixture\TestFixture::create() - CORE\src\TestSuite\Fixture\TestFixture.php, line 306
DebugKit\Model\Table\RequestsTable::ensureTables() - ROOT\vendor\cakephp\debug_kit\src\Model\Table\LazyTableTrait.php, line 56
DebugKit\Model\Table\RequestsTable::initialize() - ROOT\vendor\cakephp\debug_kit\src\Model\Table\RequestsTable.php, line 52
Cake\ORM\Table::__construct() - CORE\src\ORM\Table.php, line 290
Cake\ORM\Locator\TableLocator::_create() - CORE\src\ORM\Locator\TableLocator.php, line 212
Cake\ORM\Locator\TableLocator::get() - CORE\src\ORM\Locator\TableLocator.php, line 179
Cake\ORM\TableRegistry::get() - CORE\src\ORM\TableRegistry.php, line 110
DebugKit\ToolbarService::saveData() - ROOT\vendor\cakephp\debug_kit\src\ToolbarService.php, line 172
DebugKit\Routing\Filter\DebugBarFilter::afterDispatch() - ROOT\vendor\cakephp\debug_kit\src\Routing\Filter\DebugBarFilter.php, line 139
Cake\Event\EventManager::_callListener() - CORE\src\Event\EventManager.php, line 426
Cake\Event\EventManager::dispatch() - CORE\src\Event\EventManager.php, line 391
Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher::dispatchEvent() - CORE\src\Event\EventDispatcherTrait.php, line 78
Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher::dispatch() - CORE\src\Http\ActionDispatcher.php, line 100
Cake\Http\BaseApplication::__invoke() - CORE\src\Http\BaseApplication.php, line 83
Cake\Http\Runner::__invoke() - CORE\src\Http\Runner.php, line 65
Cake\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware::__invoke() - CORE\src\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware.php, line 62
Cake\Http\Runner::__invoke() - CORE\src\Http\Runner.php, line 65
Cake\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware::__invoke() - CORE\src\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware.php, line 88
Cake\Http\Runner::__invoke() - CORE\src\Http\Runner.php, line 65
AssetCompress\Middleware\AssetCompressMiddleware::__invoke() - ROOT\vendor\markstory\asset_compress\src\Middleware\AssetCompressMiddleware.php, line 56
Cake\Http\Runner::__invoke() - CORE\src\Http\Runner.php, line 65
Cake\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware::__invoke() - CORE\src\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php, line 81
Cake\Http\Runner::__invoke() - CORE\src\Http\Runner.php, line 65
Cake\Http\Runner::run() - CORE\src\Http\Runner.php, line 51
Cake\Http\Server::run() - CORE\src\Http\Server.php, line 90
require - ROOT\webroot\index.php, line 37
[main] - ROOT\index.php, line 16
```

IIS has full write permission to the project root folder (on the network share). The fact that CakePHP error log has captured the above info. proves it. So this is definitely not about file / folder permissions.

What's could be the cause of this error and how to fix?

Thank you.

Comment: The cause is obviousy? Your DB fails: `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 10 disk I/O error`. So simply check the SQL docs or Google for it?

Comment: That's not very helpful. I wouldn't be posting here unless I didn't find what I was looking for on Google.